# On not getting an identity matrix with dot product of matrix and its inverse while using numpy.linalg.inv()

Tags: python, matrix

```
from numpy.linalg import inv, qr
X = np.random.randn(5, 5)
mat = X.T.dot(X)
inv(mat)
mat.dot(inv(mat))
```

dot product of matrix and its inverse should be Identity matrix.
But, here output is-

```
array([[ 1.00000000e+00,  6.70961522e-16,  3.98202719e-16,
        -2.04084178e-15,  3.07963387e-16],
       [-6.46120445e-15,  1.00000000e+00,  4.44698794e-16,
         1.40254635e-15,  2.71601492e-16],
       [ 3.00736839e-15, -5.65091222e-16,  1.00000000e+00,
         1.63129995e-16, -6.43576692e-17],
       [ 1.01120865e-14, -1.23622826e-15, -6.99882344e-16,
         1.00000000e+00, -1.13627444e-16],
       [-6.31447442e-15,  2.46897480e-15,  9.95010178e-16,
        -2.81959392e-15,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

Please explain.

Answer (score 0):

That must be due to the algorithm rounding but I've found that if you diagonalize the matrix and calculate the dot product with the inverse you end up correctly with the identity matrix. This might be due to a different algorithm used to calculate the inverse matrix for a diagonal matrix.

```
import numpy as np
m = np.random.randn(5,5)
print(np.linalg.det(m))
e = np.linalg.eig(m)[0]
mdiag = np.eye(5)*e
print(mdiag.dot(np.linalg.inv(mdiag)))
```

This method seems to work always for 3x3 matrix but some times fails for bigger matrixes since there is an immaginary part left in the order of 1e-17